# lists present inside a nested list is are not showing up as indexed while appending(index changed)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, matrix, nested-lists

first, I made a nested list matrix that contains only 0's. Then I'm trying to change values for certain indexes in the nested list. but while printing the list, the order is not being maintained. Please help with this

```
h, n, c = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
mincost = []
for i in range(0, h):
    mincost.append([])
    for j in range(0, c):
            mincost[i].append(0)
for i in range(0, n):
    shop,price = [int(p) for p in input().split()]

    for j in range(0,h):
        if j == shop:
            for k in range(0, c):
                #print(j)
                mincost[i][k] = (k+1)*price
#to print as a matrix
for i in range(0, h):
     for j in range(0, c):
         print(i,end="line ")
         print(mincost[i][j],end=' ')
     print()
#to print as a nested list
print(mincost)
```

This is the input

```
5 2 9
0 4
4 9
```

this is what i got on printing as in matrix form

```
4 8 12 16 20 24 28 32 36 
9 18 27 36 45 54 63 72 81 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

This is what i got in nested list form

```
[[4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28, 32, 36], [9, 18, 27, 36, 45, 54, 63, 72, 81], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

I think the index of the list with index `0` should be actually `4`.

I'm not getting where is a mistake or if a concept is applied which I don't know

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: So you wants to print this nested output list in single string form?

Comment: `4 8 12 16 20 24 28 32 36 `\n
`0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 `\n
`0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 `\n
`0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 `\n`9 18 27 36 45 54 63 72 81`  no actually see the change is being done to the nested-list at index 4, but in output it appears at index 1

Comment: this is the intended answer

Comment: Thanks got your point. now checkout my answer

Answer (score 0):

You used the wrong index to update the matrix value here:

```
for k in range(0, c):
    # print(j)
    mincost[i][k] = (k+1)*price
```

Here you should use the index `j` in place of `i`:

```
for k in range(0, c):
    # print(j)
    mincost[j][k] = (k+1)*price
```

Input:

```
5 2 9
0 4
4 9
```

Output:

```
[[4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28, 32, 36], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [9, 18, 27, 36, 45, 54, 63, 72, 81]
]
```

Comment: @AbritPalSingh , please upvote/accept this as answer if it helps you. Thanks